# Configuration file cannot be accessed, insufficient permissions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, permissions

I apparently, according to this error, cannot access my site:

> Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

which basically means it cannot access my web.config file due to it not having permission to do so.

I tried goint to `control panel->programs->turn windows features on/off->IIS->ADF->click ASP.net`

and yet I still do not have access to my configuration file.

How can I tell IIS to give permission to this file? I am running version 7 on windows 7 64bit if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
In web.config insert
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <allow users="*"/>
</authentication>
```

This gives everybody permission to view your site